# Does block inside viewmodelscope runs on Main thread or background thread?

Tags: android, database, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I recently checked the internal code of viewModelScope which is

`CloseableCoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate)`

So my question is does the block inside the viewModelScope really runs on Main thread if yes, then how or which scope should I use to access or run DB operation inside view model? Because DB operation should run on background thread

Comment: You can use a more relevant Dispatcher for performing heavy/background tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Coroutine launched using `viewModelScope.launch {}` by default runs on the **Main Thread**. If the DB operations are `suspend` (functions marked with `suspend` keyword) then it is safe to call them on the **Main Thread**:

```
val dao = ...

viewModelScope.launch {
    // DB operation
    dao.getItem() // Note: getItem() must be a `suspend` function
}
```

If DB operations are not `suspend` then you can use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` to switch context to **Background Thread**:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    runDBInBackground()
}

suspend fun runDBInBackground() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // DB operation
    dao.getItem() // Note: getItem() is a blocking function (not suspend)
}
```

Comment: What happens in the background when we set method as suspend?

Comment: If you use `Room` you can mark methods of DAO classes as `suspend`, under the hood they switch context to background thread using `withContext`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code

```
     //If dao.getItem() is not suspend function
     viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          dao.getItem() 
     }


     //If dao.getItem() is suspend function
     viewModelScope.launch {
          dao.getItem() 
     }
```